# Error: hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a help about "hexadecimal value 0x00 is an invalid character c#" Which is also shown in picture as well.The problem is when i am trying to connect with sql server database this error appear.

[image]

Comment: 0x00 represents null in hexadecimal and null is invalid in a few places, eg XML. What are you trying to do with this value?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036799/hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-a-invalid-character), this error has to do with XML which does not allow a character of byte `0x00`. Look for a file that contains XML (like the .edmx file) and see if it has such a character and remove it if you can.

Comment: Where i can find that xml file please help me because this error is annoying me when ever i am trying to connect with database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `app.config` file. In my project I save some user strings in settings that may contain strange characters. This was the cause of a similar error.