# Why does adding services.AddDataProtection() to Startup.cs fix XmlException and CryptographicException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am following along with the Asp.net Core MVC tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

My project works when navigating to Students/Index but when I navigate to Students/Edit/1 I have the below error.

```
XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)

CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)
```

I found a solution to this issue on another post on this website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576117/cryptographicexception-for-scaffold-identity-in-asp-net-core).

While this solution does work for me I am wondering why this step is necessary? I know my question may be broad but how would I know by looking at the errors below to add the services.AddDataProtection to the configure services in Startup.cs? I would comment on the question where I found the solution but I do not have enough reputation.

Below is the full text of the errors.

XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(string res, string[] args)
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(Stream stream)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository.ReadElementFromFile(string fullPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository.GetAllElementsCore()+MoveNext()
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>..ctor(IEnumerable<T> collection)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository.GetAllElements()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.GetAllKeys()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, bool forceRefresh)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)
```

CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(byte[] plaintext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Serialize(AntiforgeryToken token)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.Serialize(IAntiforgeryFeature antiforgeryFeature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.AntiforgeryExtensions.GetHtml(IAntiforgery antiforgery, HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.DefaultHtmlGenerator.GenerateAntiforgery(ViewContext viewContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
AspNetCore.Views_Students_Edit.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Additional code:

controller for edit

```
// GET: Students/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContosoConnectionString")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys\"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Student model

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

SchoolContext

```
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }                       
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean that , after running the program in vs, you can visit the home page and other pages normally but when you enter localhost:xx/Students/Edit/1 then it throws exception? Did you add break point in the action to debug which line-code lead the exception or it even didn't enter the method?

Comment: And have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036799/hexadecimal-value-0x00-is-a-invalid-character/11039155)? It offers some guess on the exception. And I'm afraid you need to offer more details on your project.

Comment: I ran it through the debugger adding a break point where the context loads the data and where the view returning the view. It doesn't error until I step through the return View() for the edit and the details page so I can't exactly identify where it is breaking. The index page that loads all of the students loads just fine.

I am not using XML anywhere as the user in that question is. Adding the services.AddDataProtection line makes it all work but I do not understand why.

I have added additional code.

Comment: Could you pls comment `services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();` in startup file and  `public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }`  in your Student entity? I also followed official doc to connect my asp.net core project to sql server with ef core and I compared yours with mine, these are the differences. Could you pls take a try?